# Xpath expression to find values that start with

Tags: xml, xpath, startswith

I need an `Xpath` expression that will select values that start with a certain value. For this instance I am using the `id` field.

```
@id=[starts-with(name(),'value')
```

The following does not work. Is there a way to use the `starts-with` command with the value between the tags? Or is there another means in `Xpath` of selecting a matching a value with a known value.

Here is a sample of the XML I am trying to drill into:

```html
<bean>
    <id>AnnotationsBasedJMXAutoExporter</id>
    <class>org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter</class>
    <lazy-init>false</lazy-init>
    <property>assembler
        <!-- will create management interface using annotation metadata -->
        <bean></bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: What XML should be matched by this?

Comment: @choroba wouldn't this just match to the attribute tags rather than the value within the tags? I am after the value within the tags. Not the tag name

Answer (score 69):

I think this xpath should work `//id[starts-with(text(),'Annotations')]`

Comment: +1, though I'd recommend using `.` rather than `text()`, i.e. `//id[starts-with(., 'whatever')]`.  As a general rule you should avoid using `text()` in XPath expressions unless you are really sure that you need it.  Remember that it means "the set of all text node children of ..." (or "the first text node child of ..." if you're treating it as a string), which is not necessarily the same as "the text value of ..."

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to replace your `id` tagname with `div` for these examples,
to avoid confusion with attribute `id`.

**First way:**

```
//div[starts-with(text(), 'Annotations')]:
```

This `XPath` expression selects `<div>` elements that have an immediate child [text node](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-Text-Nodes) that starts-with 'Annotations`.

Second Way:

```
//div[starts-with(., 'Annotations')]:
```

This `XPath` expression selects `<div>` elements whose [string value](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) is starts-with 'Annotations`.

[For detailed explanation about the difference between these two ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240763/xpath-difference-between-dot-and-text)