# XPath: difference between dot and text()

Tags: selenium, xpath

My question is about specifics of using dot and `text()` in `XPath`. For example, following `find_element` lines returns same element:

```
driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com/')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[text()="Ask Question"]')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[.="Ask Question"]')
```

So what is the difference? What are the benefits and drawbacks of using `.` and `text()`?

Comment: My answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/38208411/423105 describes the difference between using `text()`, which selects a text node, and using an more general node selector (like `.`) in a comparison.

Comment: See also [**Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34593753/290085).

Answer (score 161, accepted):

There is a difference between `.` and `text()`, but this difference might not surface because of your input document.

If your input document looked like (the simplest document one can imagine given your XPath expressions)

**Example 1**

```
<html>
  <a>Ask Question</a>
</html>
```

Then `//a[text()="Ask Question"]` and `//a[.="Ask Question"]` indeed return exactly the same result. But consider a different input document that looks like

**Example 2**

```
<html>
  <a>Ask Question<other/>
  </a>
</html>
```

where the `a` element also has a child element `other` that follows immediately after "Ask Question". Given this second input document, `//a[text()="Ask Question"]` still returns the `a` element, while `//a[.="Ask Question"]` does not return anything!

---

This is because the meaning of the two predicates (everything between `[` and `]`) is different. `[text()="Ask Question"]` actually means: return true if any of the text nodes of an element contains exactly the text "Ask Question". On the other hand, `[.="Ask Question"]` means: return true if the **string value** of an element is identical to "Ask Question".

In the XPath model, text inside XML elements can be partitioned into a number of *text nodes* if other elements interfere with the text, as in **Example 2** above. There, the `other` element is between "Ask Question" and a newline character that also counts as text content.

To make an even clearer example, consider as an input document:

**Example 3**

```
<a>Ask Question<other/>more text</a>
```

Here, the `a` element actually contains *two* text nodes, "Ask Question" and "more text", since both are direct children of `a`. You can test this by running `//a/text()` on this document, which will return (individual results separated by `----`):

```
Ask Question
-----------------------
more text
```

So, in such a scenario, `text()` returns a set of individual nodes, while `.` in a predicate evaluates to the string concatenation of all text nodes. Again, you can test this claim with the path expression `//a[.='Ask Questionmore text']` which will successfully return the `a` element.

---

Finally, keep in mind that some XPath functions can only take one single string as an input. As LarsH has pointed out in the comments, if such an XPath function (e.g. `contains()`) is given a sequence of nodes, it will only process the *first* node and silently ignore the rest.

Comment: In example 3, what would be result for [text()="Ask Question"], will it return <a> or nothing.

Comment: Finally, now I understand text() and contains(). Very helpful comment!

Answer (score 30):

There is big difference between `dot (".")` and `text()` :-

- The `dot (".")` in `XPath` is called the **"context item expression"** because it refers to the context item. This could be match with a node (such as an `element`, `attribute`, or `text node`) or an atomic value (such as a `string`, `number`, or `boolean`). While `text()` refers to match only `element text` which is in `string` form.
- The `dot (".")` notation is the current node in the DOM. This is going to be an object of type Node while Using the `XPath` function text() to get the text for an element only gets the text up to the **first inner element**. If the text you are looking for is after the **inner element** you must use the current node to search for the string and not the `XPath` text() function.

For an example :-

```
<a href="something.html">
  <img src="filename.gif">
  link
</a>
```

Here if you want to find anchor `a` element by using text **link**, you need to use `dot (".")`. Because if you use `//a[contains(.,'link')]` it finds the anchor `a` element but if you use `//a[contains(text(),'link')]` the `text()` function does not seem to find it.

Hope it will help you..:)

Comment: I'm quite sure that I can match anchor with `//a[contains(text(),'link')]` as well as with `//a[normalize-space(text())='link')]` :)  Anyway, thanks for answer

Comment: @Andersson yeah off-course but not using `text()` directly..:)

Comment: @Andersson: You have a good point, but that only works if `link` is in the first text node child of `a`. In Saurabh's example, there may be a whitespace-only text node before the `<img>` element, in which case the  XPath expressions in your comment wouldn't match the anchor. The reason is that the `contains()` and `normalize-space()` functions take the string value of the *first* node in the node-set that is their first argument.

Comment: @SaurabhGaur: You've got some good points, but it's not true that `text()` only selects text up to the first inner element. `text()` selects all text nodes (that are children of the context node, unless you specify a different axis). However if you pass the node set selected by `text()` to `contains()`, as you did, then it is converted to a string, by taking the string value of the **first** node in the node set. (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string)

Comment: As @LarsH has correctly pointed out, some parts of this answer are still wrong and should be amended. The most important misconception in the answer is that `text()` only selects the _first_ text node, which is entirely untrue.

Comment: @MathiasMüller: Probably one of us should post a correct answer. :-)

Comment: @LarsH True ;-). I just did that, tell me if something is inaccurate / missing.

Comment: ***(-1) This answer is misleading.***  Read LarsH and Mathias' comments to understand how, or, better, see [**Mathias's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41862373/290085) and/or [**Lars' answer to another question**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38208411/290085) and/or [**my answer to another question**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46488908/290085) to better understand the subtleties here.

Answer (score -4):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QocBk.png)
**The XPath text() function locates elements within a text node while dot (.) locate elements inside or outside a text node.** In the image description screenshot, the XPath text() function will only locate Success in **DOM Example 2**. It will not find success in **DOM Example 1** because it's located between the  tags.

In addition, the text() function will not find success in **DOM Example 3** because success does not have a direct relationship to the element . Here's a video demo explaining the difference between text() and dot (.) https://youtu.be/oi2Q7-0ZIBg