# How can I use xpath to find element with optional sub element?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I'm using Selenium with xpath to get certain elements. I have a html page with the following elements:

```
<td>A</td>
<td><em>B</em></td>
```

I've tried using the following xpath expression to find td elements:

```
//td[contains(text(), 'A')] 
//td[contains(text(), 'B')]
```

The expression finds `<td>A</td>` but not `<td><em>B</em></td>`

How can I write an xpath expression which finds td tags with both no sub element and one or more sub elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead

```
//td[contains(., 'A')]
//td[contains(., 'B')]
```

This will return the td tags. The difference between . and text() you can refer here - [XPath: difference between dot and text()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240763/xpath-difference-between-dot-and-text).

Comment: Note that use of `contains()` here will also match `<td>AA</td>`, `<td>A monkey</td>`, etc.  This may or may not be desirable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [**understand**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34595441/290085) the difference between [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593753/testing-text-nodes-vs-string-values-in-xpath/34595441#34595441).

Here, you want to test the string value of `td`:

```
//td[. = 'B']
```

That way, both

```
<td>B</td>
```

and

```
<td><em>B</em></td>
```

will be selected, regardless of the `em`.

Comment: Thanks, but i'd like to have contains, not equals.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ancestor` to get the first `<td>` tag

```
//*[contains(text(), 'A')]/ancestor::td[1]
//*[contains(text(), 'B')]/ancestor::td[1]
```

And in general use

```
String text = "A";
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), '" + text + "')]/ancestor::td[1]"));
```

Comment: With this selector it will return the innermost tag which is em but the person is looking for td tag.

Comment: Thanks, but I just want the td elements with matching texts.