# xpath selector tr given list of data

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors, cucumber

I am automating a web system using selenium webdriver, in multiple scenarios I need to assert that given data in in one line (tr) of the web page.

For example, I need to assert that there is in the system a line (tr) with these data:
Data 1, Data 2, Data 3, Data 4

And my page is structured like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>Data 1</td>
    <td>Data 2</td>
    <td>Data 3</td>
    <td><span class='something'>Data 4</span></td>
<tr>
```

I wrote this xpath hoping it would return the table row:

```
.//tr[td[text()='Data 1']]/parent::tr/td[text()='Data 2']/parent::tr/td[text()='Data 3']/parent::tr/td[text()='Data 4']
```

It works until `Data 3` but in Data 4 does not work

Comment: Duplicate of [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593753/testing-text-nodes-vs-string-values-in-xpath)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would want a solution that is generic in point of match any level inside my td

You should try [using `.` instead of `text()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240763/xpath-difference-between-dot-and-text/38240971#38240971) which would be a generic solution as below :-

```
.//tr[td[.='Data 1'] and td[.='Data 2'] and td[.='Data 3'] and td[.='Data 4']]
```

Or if you want leading and trailing whitespace as well try using [`normalize-space()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) function of the `xpath` as below :-

```
.//tr[td[normalize-space()='Data 1'] and td[normalize-space()='Data 2'] and td[normalize-space()='Data 3'] and td[normalize-space()='Data 4']]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because there is a `<span>` element embedded in 4-th `<td>`.

You should try

```
.//tr[td[text()='Data 1']]/.../parent::tr/td[.='Data 4']
```

or

```
.//tr[td[text()='Data 1']]/.../parent::tr/td[span[text()='Data 4']]
```

Comment: Got it, but I cannot anticipate whether there will be a tag inside containing my data or not, so I would want a solution that is generic in point of match any level inside my td

Comment: In this case use dot (`.`) instead of `text()`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this XPath, I think it will work in your case:

```
.//tr[.//*[.='Data 1'] and [.='Data 2'] and [.='Data3'] or [.='Data 4']]
```

It will search for a tr node that has child contains these text.