# Use of contains in Selenium XPath

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath

What is the difference between `//div[contains(text(),'abc')]` and `//div[contains(.,'abc')]`?

Is "." here is used as a regular expression meaning any text that starts with `abc`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath: difference between dot and text()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240763/xpath-difference-between-dot-and-text)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `text()` test selects all text node children *of the context node*.

The dot (`.`) selects the context node itself.

As arguments of [`contains()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains) function, both `.` and `text()` are interpreted as [string value](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-string-value)s which is concatenation of all the child text nodes (see ["Element Nodes"](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#element-nodes)):

> The string-value of an element node is the concatenation of the string-values of all text node descendants of the element node in document order.

In the case of `text()`, the result is computed as concatenation of all direct text node values. In the case of `.`, the text values of all descendant text nodes are concatenated.

Consider this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>abc</div>
    <div>444 <span>abc</span></div>
    <div>def</div>
    <div>123 abc</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`//div/text()` selects the following:

- "abc"
- "444 "
- "def"
- "123 abc".

`//div/.`:

- "abc"
- "444 abc"
- "def"
- "123 abc"

Thus, `//div[contains(text(),'abc')]` selects only two `div`s:

```
<div>abc</div>
<div>123 abc</div>
```

while `//div[contains(.,'abc')]` selects all `div`s with a text node containing `abc`:

```
<div>abc</div>
<div>444 <span>abc</span></div>
<div>123 abc</div>
```