# Xpath involving a starts-with not working

Tags: selenium, xpath

I'm stuck on a problem with an xpath expression. Could some body help me, please?

So my xpath is - `".//td[starts-with(text(), 'IMT - Office Admin:')]"`

DOM :

```
<td>
 <input type="checkbox" name="partyEditF:j_id698:6:j_id700">
                IMT - Office Admin: Ability to edit everything within your office including the office's information and listings
</td>
```

Comment: I'm writing to you as a reviewer because this is your first question. The main thing I would say about your question is that it doesn't indicate what help you would like. Is it that you want the contents of the **input**?

Comment: And if someone gives you an answer that works you should please mark it accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `XPath` doesn't work because actually text starts with spaces/new line characters, so you need to get rid of them. Try below expression

```
.//td[starts-with(normalize-space(.), 'IMT - Office Admin')]
```

Comment: for any copy pasters - [text vs . DOES make a difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240763/xpath-difference-between-dot-and-text)