# How to select the drop-down items which is out of tag using xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath

I've tried several xpath's for choosing the dropdown list. But nothing is worked.

Some of the xpath's I used are as follows:

```
By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/span").click;
```

Or

```
By.xpath("/td[2]/span[contains(text(),'NATIONAL IDENTITY DOCUMENT')]").click;
```

Please find the below html tags, I need to select the value either 'ASYLUM SEEKER PERMIT DOCUMENT' or 'NATIONAL IDENTITY DOCUMENT'.

```
<tbody>
<tr id="jP2Qrg" class="z-comboitem">
<td class="z-comboitem-img"/>
<td class="z-comboitem-text">
<span class="z-comboitem-spacer"/>
ASYLUM SEEKER PERMIT DOCUMENT
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="jP2Qsg" class="z-comboitem z-comboitem-over">
<td class="z-comboitem-img"/>
<td class="z-comboitem-text">
<span class="z-comboitem-spacer"/>
NATIONAL IDENTITY DOCUMENT
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

When I try to take xpath using firepath, it is dynamic. Every time the xpath and the id is keep changing. So please suggest the xpath which works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out the solution for selecting the dropdown options.

By using List method, I took the list of options available in that field and selected by using clicking the index value of list.

```
 List<WebElement> Idtype = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[2]/td[2][@class = 'z-comboitem-text']"));
    Idtype.get(0).click();
```

Answer (score 2):

The text is not inside the span text and it is in second td tag. you can try with small change in your code as given below.

```
By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]").click;
```

or

```
By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'NATIONAL IDENTITY DOCUMENT')]").click;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this as well. But it didn't work.

Comment: But, In firepath when I use the below 1. It is getting highlighted. But not working inn the script.

    By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2][@class = 'z-comboitem-text']").click;

Comment: you can try clicking on image instead of text. By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[@class = 'z-comboitem-img']").click;

Comment: No luck, It is clicking on drop-down and not getting the value selected. Getting exception error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this..,

```
By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'NATIONAL IDENTITY DOCUMENT')]").click;

By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'ASYLUM SEEKER PERMIT DOCUMENT')]").click;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this before and it didn't work.

Comment: What is the err message. Have you mentioned any implicit wait?

Comment: The above xpath is not even getting highlighted in firepath.

Comment: Can you give me the site URL

Comment: Can you open it in Chrome, F12 ,copy as xpath and check?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below XPath to match required option:

```
By.xpath("//td[normalize-space()='ASYLUM SEEKER PERMIT DOCUMENT']").click;
```

or

```
By.xpath("//td[.='ASYLUM SEEKER PERMIT DOCUMENT']").click;
```

As @Murthi said, text node is not a child of `span`, but `td`. Note that there are [some specifics in locating text nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240763/xpath-difference-between-dot-and-text)

Comment: Can you share exception log?

Comment: This is the exception I got. 

<<< Unable to Click button OBJ_IDType_DROPDOWN >>> Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: [[InternetExplorerDriver: internet explorer on WINDOWS (b924b52b-0aee-4092-a430-2759ac4ec637)] -> xpath: //table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2][@class = 'z-comboitem-text']]


Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'


System info: host: '0967JNBPBB010L', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_76-ea'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver

Comment: It's not my Xpath in provided stacktrace. Do not use `tbody` tag in your XPath. Can you share exact output when applying my solution?

Comment: Yes, the Xpath which is provided in stacktrace is not given by you. But this is the only xpath getting highlighted in application using firpath. //tr[2]/td[2][@class = 'z-comboitem-text']

Comment: Did you try it in Firepath only? Try in Selenium code

Comment: Nope, I tried in both firepath as well as selenium code. I'm getting same exception error. 

<<< Unable to Click button OBJ_IDType_DROPDOWN >>> Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: [[InternetExplorerDriver: internet explorer on WINDOWS (f9fd0055-0f34-4830-84ed-aef18e263181)] -> xpath: //td[normalize-space()='ASYLUM SEEKER PERMIT DOCUMENT']]
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'

Comment: Did you click on appropriate element to populate drop-down menu? Can you update the ticket with some more code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

To click on `ASYLUM SEEKER PERMIT DOCUMENT` you can use the following `xpath`:

```
By.xpath("//td[contains(.,'ASYLUM SEEKER PERMIT DOCUMENT') and not (@class='z-comboitem-spacer')]").click;
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score 0):

How about this xpaths,

Updated code

```
(//td[2])[1]//*[starts-with(@class,"z-com")]; // Selects ASYLUM..
(//td[2])[2]//*[starts-with(@class,"z-com")]; // Selects NATIONAL..
```

This should work if it doesn't have same class name in the same position.

Old xpath's

```
driver.findelement(By.xpath("(//td[2])[1]")); // selects ASYLUM SEEKER PERMIT DOCUMENT 

driver.findelement(By.xpath("(//td[2])[2]")); // selects NATIONAL IDENTITY DOCUMENT
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Since there are lot of td[2] in that application. Even I tried with this now, It didn't work.