# How can we extract particular elements value by using xpath when element value is different for each element

Tags: xpath, scrapy

How can we extract ABC, XYZ by using xpath

```
<div id="desc" class="description">

    <span class="category">Name:</span> <span class="category-detail"><a href="/name/">Name</a></span>
    <br/>
    <span class="category">Address:</span> <span class="category-detail">ABC, XYZ</span>
    <br/>
    <span class="category">Room No:</span> <span class="category-detail">20</span>
    <br/>
```

I tried with

```
 response.xpath('//div[span="Address:"]/span/text()').extract()
```

but then I get `[Name, ABC,XYZ, 20]` but i require only `ABC, XYZ`.

Comment: Are you using Scrapy?

Comment: Yes, I am using scrapy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below `XPath` to get required output:

```
//div[@id="desc"]/span[.="Address:"]/following-sibling::span[1]/text()
```

Comment: could you please let me know why you used period in [.="Address:]

Comment: In this case it means content of `span`. You can use `text()="Address:"` as well. You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240763/xpath-difference-between-dot-and-text) to get more details

Comment: any solution by using css selector ?

Comment: You can try something like `div#desc span.category-detail:nth-child(5)`, but it looks less reliable

Comment: Thanks a lot
with the same question: 
<span class="category">Room No:</span> <span class="category-detail">
      <a href="xyz.com">XYZ</a></span>
then how can we extract href value (xyz.com) from this

Comment: @PradeepMishra This [blogpost](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/10/27/an-introduction-to-xpath-with-examples/) could be good introduction to XPath.

Comment: I tried with //div[@id="desc"]/span[.="Address:"]/following-sibling::span[1]/a/@href and got it :) by the way could you please tell me from where i can learn this types of complex xpath

Comment: @TomášLinhart: Thank you very much :)

Comment: @PradeepMishra, you can check [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp). It can be useful for you

Answer (score 0):

```
//div[@id="desc"]//span[text()='Address:']//following::span[1]/text()
```

Use this xpath instead.

or

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("file:///C:/Users/sv/Desktop/docUpload.html");
    List<WebElement> spanList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@id='desc']/span"));
    for (int i =0 ;i < spanList.size();i++){
        String text = spanList.get(i).getText();
        if(text.equals("ABC, XYZ")){
            System.out.println(text);
        }
    }
```

You can loop through the element lists.

Comment: Yes, Xpath gives proper result. Thanks.. btw could you please tel me know where i can learn these types of complex xpaths

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp
https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html
http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/choosing-effective-xpath/
http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/xpath-tutorial-for-selenium , Go through these sites.

Comment: Thank you vey much