# using regex with xml2?

Tags: r, regex, xpath, xml2

Consider this simple example

```
example_xml <- '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<file>
<book>
<text>abracadabra</text>
<node></node>
</book>
<book>
<text>hello world</text>
<node></node>
</book>
</file>'

myxml <- xml2::read_xml(example_xml)
```

Now, running this works as expected

```
> myxml %>% xml_find_all('//book')
{xml_nodeset (2)}
[1] <book>\n  <text>abracadabra</text>\n  <node/>\n</book>
[2] <book>\n  <text>hello world</text>\n  <node/>\n</book>
```

but looking for nodes whose `text` attribute contain `wor` does not.

```
> myxml %>% xml_find_all('//book[contains(@text, "wor")]')
{xml_nodeset (0)}
```

What is the problem here? How can I use regex (or partial string matching) with `xml2` ?

Thanks!

Comment: You do not have text attributes. You have `text` nodes inside `book` nodes. Try `xml_find_all('//book/text[contains(., "wor")]')`

Comment: whoaa thanks but what is this crazy syntax `[contains(.` with a dot?

Comment: *text* is a node and not attribute, so no need of `@`.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41862373/3832970) to learn more about the difference between `text()` and `.`. BTW, maybe you need `xml_find_all(myxml, '//book[contains(., "wor")]')`? The result is `[1] <book>\n  <text>hello world</text>\n  <node/>\n</book>`, while the top comment solution yields `[1] <text>hello world</text>`

Comment: I would post that as an answer. that is interesting thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `//book[contains(@text, "wor")]` XPath finds `book` nodes that contain a `text` attribute (`@` specifies an attribute) that contain `wor` in their values.

Your XML does not contain elements like `<book text="Hello world">Title</book>`, thus there are no results.

You may get the book nodes that contain `wor` in their text nodes using

```
> xml_find_all(myxml, '//book[contains(., "wor")]')
{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] <book>\n  <text>hello world</text>\n  <node/>\n</book>
```

If you are fine with just `text` nodes as the return values, you may use

```
> xml_find_all(myxml, '//book/text[contains(., "wor")]')
{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] <text>hello world</text>
```

If you need to get all `book` parents that contain any child nodes with `wor` text inside, use

```
> xml_find_all(myxml, '//*[contains(., "wor")]/parent::book')
{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] <book>\n  <text>hello world</text>\n  <node/>\n</book>
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41862373/3832970) to learn more about the difference between `text()` and `.`. In short, `[contains(., "wor")]` returns true if the string value of an element contains `wor`.

Comment: amazing. just a follow up question. How can I get all the parents nodes of the nodes that contain `wor`?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ Do you mean `xml_find_all(myxml, '//*[contains(., "wor")]/parent::book')`? See my edit with a test.