# What is . (dot) in xpath at place of attribute?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

At some places, I saw element like following -

```
//a[.='Assignment']
```

Generally we've syntax like - `//tagName[attributeKey='attributeValue']` or `//tagName[text()='textValue']`

But what is intention of `.` in xpath `//a[.='Assignment']`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath: difference between dot and text()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240763/xpath-difference-between-dot-and-text)

Answer (score 0):

I'll use XPath 2.0 terminology here: XPath 1.0 has different terminology but the effect of the expression is the same.

"." refers to the context item: that is, the `a` element that you are testing against the predicate. Its value here is a node. When a node is used as an argument of "=", it is *atomized*, which means (unless your code is schema-aware, which is unlikely) that the string value of the node is compared with the other operand of "=". The string value of an element is the concatenation of all its descendant text nodes.

It sounds like you don't have ready access to an XPath reference. There are quite a few good books that cover XPath, there are online tutorials (which are highly variable in quality) and the W3C specification itself (especially for XPath 1.0) is surprisingly easy reading.