# XPath query for contains() with multiple text elements

Tags: xpath

How can I find all tags that have text "world"?

```
<c>
    <a>
        <b>hello</b>
        world
    </a>
</c>
```

Expected result should be tag 'a'.
I am trying `//a[contains(text(),'world')]` but it doesn't give anything.

This 'a' tag is kind of mix of text and another tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
(//*[contains(., "world")])[last()]
```

or if you know for sure that it will be `a` node:

```
//a[contains(.,'world')]
```

Also check the [difference between *string value* and *text node*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240763/xpath-difference-between-dot-and-text)

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question.

Comment: Welcome. You can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your issue