# Selenium Xpath using value from gettext() method not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have got the following html element in my Application.

```
  <td height="25">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
 <i>text1</i>
text2
  </td>
```

My Objective is to get the td element for my test script.For this i got the text inside the td tag using the getText method for the below element.

```
xpath = "//td/i[contains(text(),'text1')]/parent::td"
```

The method returned the following text(with beginning spaces)

```
      text1 text2
```

So i copied that text into the below xpath to get the td element.

```
xpath = "//td[contains(text(),'text1 text2')]"
```

However i get a NosuchElement Exception for the above element. How is this possible?

Note : I cannot use the first xpath in my script because there are several td elements like this with a common i tag text(text 1) but a different td tag text(text2, text3...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath: difference between dot and text()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240763/xpath-difference-between-dot-and-text)

Comment: Try `"//td[contains(normalize-space(),'text1 text2')]"`

Comment: @andersson this worked thanks! Though i disagree on this being a duplicate -question is entirely different and the 'normalize-space' method finds mention only in the comments section.

Comment: Using `normalize-space()` is a workaround for this issue. Understanding the difference between `.` and `text()` will help you avoid this issue altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium catches `WebElement`, which hold the element and all child elements text. In this case, the `<td>` element text is a combination of `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`, `text1` and `text2`, so when you get the text using the first expression you get `text1 text2`. However, there is no element in the DOM which text `text1 text2`, as `text1` belomgs to the `<i>` element. Try

```
//i[contains(text(),'text1')]/parent::td[contains(text(),'text2')]
```