# Hover over dropdown menu in Amazon

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, action, webdriverwait

I just want to hover over the "Departments" drop-down list on the Amazon website.  The code looks alright but the list is not showing.  It's the Department drop-down list I am trying to show

Here's my code

```
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.amazon.com");
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='nav-line-2']"));
    Thread.sleep(300);
    actions.moveToElement(ele);
    actions.perform();
    actions.perform();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *Mouse Hover* over the element with text as **Departments** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be visible* and use `moveToElement()` method in conjunction with `perform()` method and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class amazon_com_Departments {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("start-maximized");
          WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options);
          driver.get("https://www.amazon.com");
          WebElement department = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@id='nav-link-shopall' and normalize-space()='Departments']")));
          new Actions(driver).moveToElement(department).perform();
      }
  }
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: amazon_hover_Department]

Comment: How do you get the length of the list.  I used the code:   List<WebElement> e = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='nav-line-2' and contains(.,'Departments')]"));
  int itemsCount = e.size();
  System.out.println(itemsCount);

Comment: @squathub I am afraid you question was about **Hover over dropdown menu in Amazon** hence was my answer. If your requirement have changed can you raise a new request as per your new requirement? StackOverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out.

Comment: @squathub Upvote the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the *xpath* is not unique and with the same locator, locating 6 elements in the page. When we have more than one element with same locator, selenium go for first element. In your case, unfortunately 'Departments' is not the first element with that locator.

Change your xpath to below: [Tested & worked]

```
//span[@class='nav-line-2' and contains(.,'Departments')]
```

Comment: Is this right WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='nav-line-2' and contains(.,'Departments')]"));

Comment: whats the .,  for in the Departments bracket?

Comment: Sorry it worked thanks,  I copied your code thought mine was the same so I guess not so thanks Dhamo

Comment: It means text(), since the whole 'Department' text falls in span element we can use "." instead of "text()". You will not be able to use in few cases which are detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240763/xpath-difference-between-dot-and-text)