# How to read text with space in xpath

Tags: xpath

I have listBox with value "This is_a_test" 
( there is a space after the This )

```
$x('//li[contains(@class,"myClass")][text()="This is_a_test"]')
```

When I run it I got empty list []

I tried also

```
$x('//li[contains(@class,"myClass")][text()="This<b></b> <b></bis_a_test"]')
```

What do I need to change in my expression ?

The XML

```
<li .... >
"This"
<b></b>
<b></b>
"is_a_test"
</li>
```

Comment: Who knows, if you don't share your XML?

Comment: The problem is just how to read space in xpath if I changed the name to This_ is_a_test then it worked

Comment: I added the xml

Comment: It might be because your text() is containing double quotes. try escaping it like this `$x('//li[contains(@class,"myClass")][text()="\"This\" \"is_a_test\""]')` OR `$x('//li[contains(@class,"myClass")][text()="This\" \"is_a_test"]')`

Comment: it give me syntax error ox xpath is not a valid XPath expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser "shows" an space but in the command line you get

```
xmllint --html --xpath "//li[contains(@class,'myclass')]/text()" test.html
"This"


"is_a_test"
```

So there are 3 new lines on the result which are also part of `text()` output.

Removing new lines from the html, this XPath works (reversing quotes for simplicity)

```
echo '<li class="myclass">"This"<b></b> <b></b>"is_a_test"</li>' | \
xmllint --html --xpath "//li[contains(@class,'myclass')][.='\"This\" \"is_a_test\"']/text()" -
```

Result:

```
"This" "is_a_test"
```

Please note the dot `.` operator instead of `text()`.
It's not easy to represent new lines on an xpath expression. Also, you may want to check [this answer for more info on the difference between dot and text()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41862373/2834978).