# How to use method contain in XML documents?

Tags: xml, powershell

I want to do mapping using XML document. I use method contain to map. I tried this code:

```bsh
$ID_Unit = "1234"
$Flag_Path = "D:\Auto\File602.XML"
[xml]$Read = Get-Content $Flag_Path
$All_ID = $Read.Title.Unit

$Map_ID = $All_ID | Where-Object {$_.Contains("$ID_Unit")}

if ($Map_ID) {
    Write-Host "Match"
} else {
    Write-Host "Not Match"
}
```

but it returns this error:

> Method invocation failed because [System.Xml.XmlElement] does not contain a method named 'Contains'.

This is my XML documents looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Title>
    <Unit>
        <ID1>1234</ID1>
        <ID2>5678</ID2>
    </Unit>
</Title>
```

Comment: `$_.InnerText.Contains()`, but probably you'd rather want to do `$Map_ID = $All_ID.SelectNodes("//*[. = $ID_Unit]")`

Answer (score 1):

As [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) in above comment, you can use [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp) to check for a specific value (instead of PowerShells `-contains` operator).

Example:

```
$ID_Unit = "1234"
$xml = [xml] (Get-Content "test.xml")
$units = @($xml.SelectNodes("//Unit/*[text()=$ID_Unit]"))
if ($units.Count -gt 0){
    Write-Host "Text found"
}
```

This [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240763/xpath-difference-between-dot-and-text) gives an explantion of the difference of the XPATh `.` and 
`text()` operations.