# Selenium XPath - select element by text which is after comment

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have this HTML:

```
<div>
    <!-- \/ this div -->
    <div>
        aaa
        <!-- -->
        bbb
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to select the second `div` like this: `"//div[contains(text(), 'bbb')]"`, but selenium don't find it.

I tested this:

```
System.out.println(
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'aaa')]")).getText()
); //aaa bbb

System.out.println(
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'bbb')]")).getText()
); //Unable to locate element:...
```

Why don't find element if I looking for text which is after a comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
System.out.println(
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(., 'bbb')]")).getText()
);
```

For more info see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41862373/6845383)

Comment: Hmm...It's not perfect. For `<div><div>aaa<!-- -->bb</div></div>`, I get first div. Which is parent of `div` I want. In a real page give me the `div` which is nearest to root(`<html>`) and have a subnode with `bbb`. I updated my question html.

Comment: @KunLun can you share more of the HTML or the URL? this is a new question... I'd like to help...

Comment: I updated html from question. With your xpath I get first div.

Comment: You will have to give a more explicit path... for example `"//div/descendant::div[contains(., 'bbb')]"`