# Selenium: How can I access "computed properties" in "Accessibility" of Chrome?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I inspect the second div in Chrome, I see a new calculated property "text 1". How can I select the second div by this calculated property?

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="a">text 1</div>
<div aria-labelledby='a'>text 2</div>

</body>
</html>
```

i tried without success

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@'text 1']")
```

Comment: Xpath should be `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[.='text 1']")`

Comment: What is the purpose of .= ?

Comment: Simply text, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240763/xpath-difference-between-dot-and-text

Comment: NoSuchElementException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, your goal to get `<div aria-labelledby='a'>text 2</div>` referenced to the `<div id="a">text 1</div>` by **id** and **aria-labelledby**.
Solution is to find element by **text 1** text, get **id** attribute and use it to search second div with **aria-labelledby** attribute:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get("some url")

id = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[.='text 1']"))).get_attribute("id")
text2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(f"div[aria-labelledby='{id}']").text
# text2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//div[@aria-labelledby='{id}']").text
labelled_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(f"//div[@aria-labelledby='{id}']")
```

Comment: Thanks, that works and is a great solution. Is there no way to do this viaa xpath directive? Or a built in fiunction in selenium? I almost can't believe this.

Comment: This is the only way

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming. In my real life case, the labelled by is composed of multiple ids. Is it possible to change your last line in a way, that the xpath selects all elements where the id is *contained* in the labelledby?

Comment: That works. I used a slightly updated version with a 'contained' statement: labelled_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(f"//div[contains(@aria-labelledby, '{id}')

Answer (score 0):

You could use `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='text 1']")//following-sibling::div`

This just retrieves the `div` following another `div` with text property `text 1`.

Comment: This gives me the first div, but I want to get the second by referencing to "text 1" (which is the link between the two)

Comment: This XPath specifies that `text` equals `text 1`. Are there multiple divs on the page that share this same text value?

Comment: I want to get the second div, *but* the only information I have is "text 1", which belongs to another div. both divs are linked through a labelledby.

Comment: Makes sense. Updated my answer to get second div in this case.

Answer (score 0):

xpath expression `//div[@aria-labelledby = //div[.='text 1']/@id]/text()`
gives you "text 2" directly