# Access value from computed properties

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to access the value of an input box, I can see the value on the webpage; however, the HTML tag does not contain the actual value (it only contains "---"). Below the HTML tag and a link to a reference image

[html element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Flhq8.png)

I was able to find the actual value under Accessibility -> Computed Properties, but I'm not sure how to retrieve it from there

[accessibility information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueOXK.png)

I've tried the following with no success:

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='exttemp']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

**Output:** Empty

---

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='exttemp']"))).text)
```

**Output:** Empty

---

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='exttemp']"))).get_attribute("value"))
```

**Output:** "---"

---

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='exttemp']"))).get_property("value"))
```

**Output:** "---"

---

[This is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70414435/use-selenium-to-get-input-element-value-if-it-isnt-in-html) but it wasn't solved. I also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58148925/selenium-how-can-i-access-computed-properties-in-accessibility-of-chrome) but the aria elements are undefined in my case.

Comment: it dosent look like its this btn that have the value

Comment: Is the url publicly accessible, and if so, can you share it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('exttemp').disabled='';")
time.sleep(1)
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='exttemp']"))).get_attribute("value"))
```

As you did not confirm the url, I cannot test it.

Comment: This is a device inside a private network so I can't share the URL; however, your solution worked. Thanks! :)