# how to get the text value of xpath?

Tags: html, xpath

My HTML is following:

```
<li>
    <span>
        <strong>13. </strong>
        "For any queries, call 123456789"
    </span>
</li
```

I want to make the xpath containing the text ""For any queries" to scroll my element to this particular text. I tried to make the xpath like

**" //span//[contains(text(),'For any queries')]** "

but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case since the `span` has multiple children `text()` does not properly find the text of the `span`. This behaviour is explained here: [XPath: difference between dot and text()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240763/xpath-difference-between-dot-and-text).

To fix this particular problem the xpath could be changed to:

```
//span[contains(.,'For any queries')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 //span//[contains(text(),'For any queries')]
```

Your XPath expression is invalid since you can't put `//` before a predicate `[...]`.
`Contains` function will evaluate the first returned text node (in your case, a whitespace node).

You can use @Simon Tulling's answer or keep your original idea. Just remove the useless `//` and add a `normalize-space()` predicate to ignore the whitespace node (caused by the presence of the `strong` element in the `span` element).

In that case, the XPath expression will be :

```
//span[contains(text()[normalize-space()],'For any queries')]
```

Comment: @E Wiest Thanks for your help