# SQL how to extract value from xml string

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, xquery-sql

```
CREATE FUNCTION split_string_XML
(
    @in_string VARCHAR(MAX),
    @delimiter VARCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @list TABLE(NAMES VARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @sql_xml XML = Cast('<root><U>'+ Replace(@in_string, @delimiter, '</U><U>')+ '</U></root>' AS XML)
    
    INSERT INTO @list(NAMES)
    SELECT f.x.value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS NAMES
    FROM @sql_xml.nodes('/root/U') f(x)
    WHERE f.x.value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)') <> ''
    RETURN
END
GO
```

I am unable to understand the syntax and functionality for the below line

```
 SELECT f.x.value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)')
```

what does this '.' indicates and what is its purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `f` is not immediately obvious when reading your posted code because the author did not use an explicit `AS` keyword.

So this:

```
INSERT INTO @list(NAMES)
SELECT f.x.value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS NAMES
FROM @sql_xml.nodes('/root/U') f(x)
WHERE f.x.value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)') <> ''
```

Can be expanded to:

```
INSERT INTO
    @list( NAMES )
SELECT
    f.x.value( '.', 'VARCHAR(50)' ) AS NAMES
FROM
    @sql_xml.nodes('/root/U') AS f( x )  /*  `f` is declared here */
WHERE
    f.x.value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)') <> ''
```

The `@sql_xml.nodes('/root/U') AS f( x )` line does this:

1. `@sql_xml` is a T-SQL variable with the `XML` data-type, which is a "special" type (compared to `int` or `date`, for example) because it supports *methods* (in an OOP sense).
2. The `XML.nodes(XQuery)` method is called which extracts all `<U>` elements from the XML document structure.

   - The `nodes()` [method is documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15) btw.
3. The `AS f( x )` part is a declaration, which declares a new *derived table* called `f` that contains a single column named `x` mapped to the `<U>` elements extracted by the `nodes()` method. Note that the data-type of `x` is still `XML`.
4. The `.value( path, type )` method extracts the specified `path` and exposes it with type `type` (in this case, `varchar(50)`).

---

That said, if this function is being used to split a list of input values into a table, **don't do that**. [Instead use table-valued parameters directly so you don't need to faff around with splitting strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595353/how-to-pass-table-value-parameters-to-stored-procedure-from-net-code).

Comment: Thanks, . value (path, type) here path='.' indicates ?

Comment: When the XPath is `.` that means "self", which is the `<U>` element's `#text` content node. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240763/xpath-difference-between-dot-and-text