# Why the xpath method is not working here?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to find an element on page using xpath but every time I am getting element not found what's wrong here kindly suggest

```
Url - https://multi-verse-js.herokuapp.com/main.html

Xpath Value I am using for query -  xpath: //a[@class='active'][text()='Web-Search']

Element name I am searching - Web-search
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use partial linkText

```
partial Linktext: Web-Search 
xPath = //a[contains(text(), 'Web-Search')]
```

Comment: `//a[contains(., 'Web-Search')]` is better alterantive as there are multiple `<a>` nodes. Take a look on [XPath: difference between dot and text()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38240763/10824407).

Answer (score 2):

`//a[@class='active'][text()='Web-Search']` is finding/selecting nothing from the webpage that's why you are getting `element not found`

But the following example select element:

```
//a[contains(.,'Web-Search')]
```