# Select only the closest ancestor of any node that contains a given string, the ancestor must have a given attribute

Tags: xpath, xslt

Here is some example XML from which I only need to select the closest ancestor to an element that contains a given string, the ancestor must have the `@isDoc` attribute.

In my below example, I would expect to only get the `<example>` node in the resulting nodeset if the value of `$macroAlias` was `match`.

```
<container isDoc="">
    <site isDoc="">
        <home isDoc="">
            <page>Some text</page>
            <page>Some text</page>
            <example isDoc="">
                <title>A title</title>
                <body><![CDATA[Some text and a page containing a <p>string to match</p>]]></body>
            </example>
            <page>Some text</page>
        </home>
    </site>
</container>
```

My current query can be found below. The problem with it is that it selects not only the closest ancestor but all other ancestors above that too. I really only want the ancestor node (with the `@isDoc` attribute) of the node containing the given string (`$macroAlias`).

```
<xsl:if test="$macroAlias != ''">
    <xsl:variable name="nodes"
                  select="//node()[contains(., $macroAlias)][ancestor::*[@isDoc][1]]/parent::*[@isDoc]"/>

        <ul>
            <li>
                <xsl:for-each select="$nodes">
                    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </li>
        </ul>
</xsl:if>
```

I've tried many different ways to achieve this and either end up with the same result or no results in my output.

Comment: Your question is not clear (not to say confusing). The `example` element in your example is not ancestor of anything other than its text child node and the `isDoc` attribute . In general, the expression `ancestor::*[some condition][1]` will select the nearest ancestor that satisfies the condition. Please reduce the example to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem - see: [mcve].

Comment: I am afraid this still doesn't make sense. If the searchString is "match", then both `body` and `contact` have it in their child text nodes. For `contact`, the nearest ancestor with an `isDoc` attribute is `home`. Why should it not be included in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the `.` in `node()[contains(., $macroAlias)]` is that it will find any `node()` (also text()-nodes) that contains (all descendants included) this `$macroAlias`. See for a explanation the differnce between `text()` and `.` i.e. [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38240763/3710053)

So that is true for:

- `/container[@isDoc]` and
- `/container[@isDoc]/site[@isDoc]` and
- `/container[@isDoc]/site[@isDoc]/home[@isDoc]` and
- `/container[@isDoc]/site[@isDoc]/home[@isDoc]/example[@isDoc]` and
- `/container[@isDoc]/site[@isDoc]/home[@isDoc]/example[@isDoc]/example[@isDoc]/text()`

If the `$macroAlias` is in a child-text() of a element with *[@isDoc] (as in your example), I would try this:

```
<xsl:variable name="nodes"
              select="//*[@isDoc][contains(text(), $macroAlias)]"/>
```

If it `$macroAlias` is not a direct child of a element with a @isDoc-attribute you could use:

```
<xsl:variable name="nodes"
              select="//text()[contains(., $macroAlias)]/ancestor::*[@isDoc][1]"/>
```

Base on this xml:

```
<container isDoc="">
  <site isDoc="">
    <home isDoc="">
      <page>Some text</page>
      <page>Some text</page>
      <example isDoc="">
        <title>A title</title>
        <body><![CDATA[Some text and a page containing a <p>string to match</p>]]></body>
      </example>
      <page>Some text</page>
      <contact><![CDATA[Some text and a page containing a <p>string to not match</p>]]></contact>
    </home>
  </site>
</container>
```

using this xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:param name="macroAlias" select="'A title'"></xsl:param>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:if test="$macroAlias != ''">
      <xsl:variable name="nodes" select="//text()[contains(., $macroAlias)]/ancestor-or-self::*[@isDoc][1]"/>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <xsl:for-each select="$nodes">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </xsl:if>  
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Will give this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ul>
   <li>example</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This gets me much closer. As per another request I have tried to simplify my question and example with the expected result. The 2nd query you have given did not seem to be valid unless I put square brackets around the ancestor part `//*[contains(text(), $macroAlias)][ancestor::*[@isDoc][1]]`. Based on my example this returns `<body>` and `<contact>` nodes but should only return `<example>`

Comment: If changed ancestor::* to ancestor-or-self::* and added example code/result

Comment: I suspect you could simplify this by looking for `//text()[contains(., $macroAlias)]/ancestor::*[@isDoc][1]`. If that's really the desired logic (I am still not entirely sure). I would also add this reference to your explanation: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value

Comment: @michael.hor257k: thanks, that is simplifies it. I have changed the code. 
The advised link does not take me to something I understand

Comment: Well, the thing is that the arguments of the `contains()` function are *strings*. When the supplied argument is a *node*, it is converted to a string by returning the **string-value** of the node. Each type of node has its own string-value definition. The string-value of an element node is the concatenation of the string-values of all text node descendants of the element node in document order.  The string-value of a text node is the character data.

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed This gets me the results I needed, thank you for your perseverance and for providing the solution.