# How to verify a text which contains a <br> tag using Robot Framework

Tags: html, automated-tests, tags, robotframework

I have the following problem, I need to perform the following check: wait until the page contains... but since it contains a br tag I get an error. How could I verify that the text is visible?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKrgR.png)

I need to verify that the text is visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page could wait for webelement whose whole text is as expected.

E.g.

```
wait until page contains element  //div[.="Nuestro tableros digitales de control"]
```

Using dot `.` instead of `text()` is on purpose! Nice explanation why is, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41862373/7349134).

P.S. I retyped the expected text from your screenshot, so check for typos. For this reason, it's nice generally to provide the text source in question, instead of a screenshot.